# How to merge/combine all header sections to only one header section in Word 2010

Tags: ms-word

Does anyone help me this problem?

Now, in my word, I have around 200 header sections. How can I remove all of them (remove all header sections, not remove only its content)?

Or how can I copy only content without header/footer sections to other document?

I've searched the solution on the internet but there is no clue.

Thank you so much.

Comment: doing a bit of research I've realized that copy of headers is driven by section break characters in the text to be copied. Headers can't be removed from a document, at least a new paragraph character is there and will be copied together with the section break characters. how much difference is between formatting of different sections? are you able to remove the section breaks (it can be done quickly be find & replace)?

Comment: I've also faced a similar issue, couldn't find an optimal solution. However find & replace of ^b (section break character) or similar section breaks characters (^12 or ^m) worked for me in some documents but not always. Another option is to try pressing the show hide button (¶) (ctrl-* shortcut) and look for a ---section--- statement between sections.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the **Replace function** in Word for this.

- **Ctrl+H** gives you replace
- Click on the **More** button
- Under **Special** at the bottom of the expanded dialog you will find **"Section Break."** Click on that. *(This inserts "^b" in the Find box but I thought you would want to know where to find such things in the future.)*
- Press **Replace All**
- Then go into the header and footer and delete or use the previous suggestion of Document Inspector to remove the content.

Note, this is a programming forum and your question would be better addressed on the [Microsoft Word Answers forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1473637240674) or on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word).

Answer (score 2):

**Direct Copy from this Web page**
https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-use-sections-in-word-2013/

**How to delete a section break**
A section break is just like a character in your document. To delete the break, you can use the Backspace or Delete keys. For example: Position the insertion pointer just before the section break and then press the Delete key.

**Tip**
When you have trouble finding the section breaks, switch to Draft view: Click the Views tab and choose Draft from the Views group. You can also summon the Section indicator on the status bar. In that case, position the toothpick cursor at the top of the page and then press the Backspace key.

**Warning**
Deleting a section removes any formatting, including headers and footers, that was unique to the section. If you accidentally delete a section break, you lose any special formatting that you applied to the section. In this case, press the Undo shortcut, Ctrl+Z, before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

See if this could help.

In Word 2010, go to the File tab, click the large Check for Issues button, and select Inspect Document:
In Word 2007, Inspect Document is under the Microsoft Office Button and the Prepare menu item.

Now uncheck all boxes EXCEPT Headers, Footers, and Watermarks. Note: This tool also remove any watermarks from your document.

Click Inspect and you should see a result like this if you have headers, footers, or watermarks in your document:

Simply click Remove All to delete these. Note that you cannot undo the removal, so be sure to first save a version of the document with these elements intact if you wish to retain them.

> > Got it from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/10/19/quickly-remove-all-headers-and-footers-in-word.aspx).

Comment: thank you, but this help just remove content of headers, not remove header sections. We still have section 1, section 2,... section 185. I just want one header section.

Answer (score 0):

Click into the footer and go to Header & Footer in the Ribbon at the top and click link to previous for all the section. I managed to synchronise my footer of all the sections using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. I saw all those "hacking" replays that definitely are not working on a Mac.. Of course, MacOS doesn't like "hacking" stuff.

Solution is pretty easy, although nowhere to be found online. You go to view and select outline.

This will show the document plane and will reveal the breaking/changing line in a graphic manner. Select the line above and below and delete..

Voila! When using a Mac you work on a mouse..

PS: in the way past, Word had a similar view function revealing all special characters, that made it far easier to fix stuff..